# How to carry data from one controller to another in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I have two controllers and two models in angular. In my first view the controller combines the data provided by the two models and creates a combined view. I do not want to merge the data again in my second controller(if I want to use it again). How do I carry this combined data from first controller to the second?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular: Share data between controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/angular-share-data-between-controllers)

Comment: Use a model that is shared between both controller

Comment: read about service, factory, value, provider & constant in angular. You ll get an idea.

Comment: Thank you guys for your valuable answers, I am sorry to say but I know these solutions. I want to integrate the data from two models only once in my session cycle. If I use a factory pass two different data sets and merge them it would be done. But I have to do the same in each controller. If I have a huge data i.e. I do not want to waste time to merge a large chunk of data again and again how am I supposed to do the same?